# Unexpected && T_BOOLEAN_AND with username and password form - PHP

Tags: php, html

So I've got a very simple html page which uses a post php method to send the username and password to the php script. However I get the error: unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) when the details are passed to the script. Any ideas why?

Here's the html form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <p> Username: </p>
    <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <p> Password: </p>
    <input type="text" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And here is the login.php script:

```
 <?php
    if ($_POST["username"] == "t5" ) &&
        ($_POST["password"] == "just4fun") {    
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[‘username’] = true;
        header('Location  menu.php');
    }
    else { header('Location loginform.html') }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[‘username’]` curly quotes. *Beautiful, yet deadly*. and these will fail you `Location (file)`. RTM on that.

Comment: Dear you have forgotten to close bracket in your if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, also notice how I changed the == to ===. This is good practive when checking a string.

You were missing a ; after the else statement and the && needs to go inside of the if(condition && condition)

```
if ($_POST["username"] === "t5" && $_POST["password"] === "just4fun") 
    {    
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['username'] = true;
         header('Location: menu.php');
    } else {
         header('Location: loginform.html');
    }
```

Comment: aren't you even going to point "where" they failed?

Comment: not my dv here, should you ask yourself

Comment: Identifier? When did `==` and `===` become identifiers? And why would you change them? What difference would it make here?

Answer (score 0):

The && sign for your if statement goes inside the parentheses and there should only be one set of parentheses.

```
if ($_POST["username"] == "t5" && $_POST["password"] == "just4fun")
```

Also `[‘username’]` should have quotes `['username']`

Location should be followed with colons too.

Comment: you missed a few things

Comment: Wait what did I miss?

Comment: look over their code again, real careful like. You already added one from your original post/edited.

Comment: I caught the colons. Is there still more?

Comment: pretty much covers it. Yet, adding an `exit;`after each header wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You *could* have more than one set of parentheses, i.e `((this test) && (that test) && (the other test))`. Four sets, no waiting!